# Why is wire's inductance inversely proportional to its thickness?

Tags: inductance, coil

In all the formulas I could find, wire thickness is always in denominator, it seems. Of course thinner wire can have more loops in same space, but even in this monster of a formula for single wire:

[image: Formula]

Inductance seems to be reversely proportional to thickness somehow.

I just can't provide any logical/physical explanation for this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First consider two straight parallel wires separated by some distance, with current running in the same direction. The total inductance of these two wires (consider the current to be the sum of the current in each) is the sum of the self inductance of each wire, plus the mutual inductance between the two. Because the currents are running in the same direction, this mutual inductance adds as a positive contribution to the total inductance (i.e. a positive coupling constant). The mutual inductance of these two wires gets larger if the wires are moved closer together, and therefore the total self inductance of the two-wire 'system' also increases.

Next, think of the current in a single conductor as a bunch of small, individual current elements at their various locations within the cross section. The total inductance is the self inductance of each small current element, plus the sum over all the mutual inductances between every pair of current elements. If the wire is smaller in diameter, these current elements are all closer to one another, and so the mutual inductance increases, therefore increasing the total inductance of the conductor.

You could also approach the argument from the standpoint of the energy stored in the magnetic field, but I think this is more intuitive.

Comment: Thanks, I think it's the most intuitive answer here, others are more detailed though and good in their own right!

Comment: Wow, that's a really intuitive answer. I had always wondered this myself since it always seemed that if you thought about it, it would take more effort to get all the electrons moving in a wider diameter wire than a smaller one.

Answer (score 3):

### Coax can help us start to understand this

So, what do we know about coax: -

1. The net magnetic field external to the cable is zero when driven with identical forward and return currents i.e. the external magnetic fields cancel.
2. The magnetic field produced by the shield only exists outside the shield because magnetic fields are not produced within a current tube (basic physics).
3. The magnetic field produced by the inner wire exists in two places: -

   - between inner conductor and shield and,
   - outside the shield
4. The field outside the shield from the inner = the field from the shield but in the opposite polarity hence we have external field cancellation is in point (1)

So, given that both inner and shield carry the same magnitude of current, we can clearly see that the inner produces more magnetic field than the shield because, it produces an extra magnetic field between inner and shield. This must mean that a small diameter conductor will have more inductance than a larger diameter current tube.

But how might a larger diameter current tube relate to a larger diameter solid conductor?

### Current tube and solid conductor of same outer diameter

With the current tube, the current is forced to occupy the wall area - i.e. it cannot flow outside the confines of the tube because there is no copper there for it to flow through. On the other hand, a solid conductor will naturally use (for DC) all the cross sectional area of the copper therefore the external field is a contribution from not just the current flowing close to the surface of the conductor but from current within and all the way to the centre.

As it happens (and I'm not going to mathematically show this), the inductance of a current tube of diameter d is exactly the same inductance as a solid conductor of diameter d. In other words, the magnetic field produced by a 10 mm diameter current tube carrying (say) 100 amps is exactly the same as a 10 mm diameter solid conductor. Here's a Quickfield simulation that shows identical field pattern: -

[image]

The outer diameter is 10 mm and the tube's internal diameter is 8 mm. Aplogies for the small square outer boundary. QuickField student edition only permits a limited number of nodes and so quite tight boundary conditions were imposed.

It comes down to comparing the fields from a higher density current at the surface (current tube) against a lower but uniform (and over a greater area)  current density in a sold conductor.

### Recap

- A current tube has less inductance than a much smaller solid conductor
- A current tube has the same inductance as a solid conductor of the same outer diameter

It then follows that inductance falls as diameter increases (even if the conductor becomes a tube).

Comment: Are you sure the inductance is the same for a tube and a solid wire? Surprising result, given that the magnetic field is the same outside, but the solid wire has magnetic field inside. Therefore there is additional energy stored in that portion of the magnetic field inside the solid wire, which should mean higher inductance. Thoughts?

Comment: @rpm2718 I've added field plots now so that you can make visual comparisons. As for your comment above you have to balance the extra internal field from the whole conduction area of the solid conductor against that field only produced by thin wall currents on the current tube. In the wall-area the current densities are far greater than the solid conductor.

Comment: Thank you. Question for another day I guess. Thanks for your prolific contributions to this site. Learned a ton reading your stuff.

Comment: I see. It's probably due to the "skin effect". Most of the current tries to flow along the "skin" of a conductor, while core have almost 0 current. Maybe that's why thick conductors or tubes have less inductance, their current are spread out on a much larger total area than same current in thin wire....

Comment: @ScienceDiscoverer it is related but, in my answer, I've tried to steer away from skin effect and concentrated on DC fields and also mentioned that the current uses all the area (implication DC, not-implied is skin-effect on purpose).

Comment: Oh, yea, I remembered that skin effect only affects higher frequencies...

Answer (score 1):

The total inductance of a wire is sum of its internal and external inductance. Where internal inductance means inductance due to internal magnetic field and likewise external inductance means inductance due to external magnetic field of the wire.
Now, if you just look at the external magnetic field of the wire, you would expect that the inductance should decrease with the wire thickness.This is because a bigger radius means less magnetic field outside the wire. (Note that \$B = \frac{\mu_oI}{2\pi r}, r > d\$, thus bigger d implies bigger r, smaller B and hence smaller external inductance).
What about the internal inductance?
Assume that you are operating at low frequencies such that the current is uniformly distributed across the wire cross section. In this case, the internal inductance of the wire is actually independent of the wire radius. Why? Because the magnetic field is now given by, \$B = \frac{\mu Ir}{2\pi d^2}, r < d\$. In this case, if you increase radius d, then you also decrease the magnetic field keeping the magnetic energy inside its volume 
 constant. Hence, inductance (internal) independent of d.
Since, \$L_{tot} = L_{int} + L_{ext}\$, where \$L_{ext}\$ decreases with the radius while \$L_{int}\$ is independent of it, the total inductance falls with the radius.
This would be even more obvious at high frequencies. Above certain cutoff-frequency, the current distribution in the wire is defined by the skin effect. Here, the current instead of being uniformly distributed across the wire gets concentrated near the edges. In this scenario, the internal magnetic field will be zero! Consequently, the total inductance would only be contributed by the external inductance which falls with the radius.

Comment: So, on high frequencies thickness of the wire is even more critical to it's inductance?

Comment: @ScienceDiscoverer, In a way, yes, since after skin effect the internal inductance contribution is negligible.

Answer (score 1):

Like we define the capacitor as the ratio between the charge and the voltage, we define the inductance as the ratio between the magnetic charge (magnetic flux) and the current, such that,
$$L=\frac{\phi}{I}$$
Assume we excite two inductors with the same current *I*. Inductor 1 has a small radius *a*, and Inductor 2 has a larger radius *A* (*A>a*). Now we can say that the inductor that produces more flux, will certainly have larger inductance. Using Ampere's law we can plot the flux as a function of the radius *r* as shown below, for a=1, and A=2,

[image]

Therefore, you can conclude easily that the total flux (area under the curve) for the thinner line with radius *a* is greater than the flux of the thicker line with radius *A*.

The situation for higher frequency is more complicated, but you can derive similar conclusions.